# How to iterate through this array within an array to see if all values are equal?

Tags: ruby, arrays, each

Here is my sample code

```
:key1 => "a"
:key2 => "b"
:key3 => "c"
array1 = [[:key1, :key1, :key1],[:key1, :key2, :key3],[:key2, :key2, :key1]]
array1.each { |x| if x.sym_tos == "a"
                     puts "All match!"
                  else
                     puts "no match"
                  end
             }
```

Yet when I run it, I get the following error code:
undefined method `sym_to_s' for [:R1C1, :R1C2, :R1C3]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: Wow this question _completely_ changed on its last edit.  Quick answer to the new question: there is no `sym_tos` in Ruby.  You just want `to_s`.  That handles the undefined method error you just asked about, but there are some other errors in this code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted to say

```
if x.uniq.length == 1
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but I eventually want to switch over to strings and from a quick test that did not work. Any idea how to use it in regards to a string constant?

Comment: That seems to be a different question.

Comment: @JonnyPolo Do you mean that you want to determine whether every character in a string is distinct?

Comment: @JonnyPolo [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chars) returns an array of characters.